# Given a line graph $L(G)$, is it possible to determine whether $G$ is bipartite?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose I am given a line graph $L(G)$, but don't know $G$. Is it possible for me to determine from this information whether $G$ is bipartite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I originally thought the answer was yes which is why I posted the question, but I found that it's no.

Let $G$ be such that $E(G)=\{ \{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\}\}$ and $V(G)=\{1,2,3\}$. Then the line graph is of the form $V(L(G))=\{a,b,c\}$ and $E(L(G))=\{\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{a,c\}\}$.

[image: The complete graph $K_3$ and its line graph.]

Let $H$ be such that $E(H)=\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\}\}$ and $V(H)=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Then the line graph is of the form $V(L(H))=\{a,b,c\}$ and $E(L(H))=\{\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{a,c\}\}$.

[image: The complete bipartite graph $K_{1,3}$ and its line graph.]

$G$ is not bipartite, but $H$ is bipartite, yet they have the same line graph.

Comment: In fact this is the only counterexample. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_graph_isomorphism_theorem#Whitney_theorem

Comment: That's amazing!

Comment: This is the only *connected* counterexample.  For example "two copies of $G$" (not bipartite) and "two copies of $H$" (bipartite) have the same line graph too.